# how to install motoman_config

Tags: ros, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly new to ROS and using fuerte. can anyone advice me how to install motoman_config.

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34942/how-to-install-motoman_config/) by [samee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2455/samee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always download the package and build it. Try:

```
svn co http://swri-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/motoman
rosmake motoman
```

There also appears to be [tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/motoman/Tutorials) for it too, so take a look at them.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-26**:
Don't forget to add that working copy to your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The rosws script is a good way to manage source tree checkouts.